# split string with two delimiter to arraycollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I try to split a string to send it to arraycollection.
The problem is that each record contain several field.
With one field, I found how to do but in my case, no.

```
var str:String="12/12/2008-70,15#05/03/2005-193,50#23/04/1987-45,23";

 public function splitDouble(stringInit:String,sep1:String):ArrayCollection{


            var tempAc:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection((stringInit.split(sep1)));
            return tempAc;
        }

    }
```

Record delimiter is '#', field delimiter is ','.
I'd like to add something like that:
tempAc[0][0]==12/12/2008;
tempAc[0][1]==70,15;

Thanks

So, can you help me to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear what you want to do.  "The problem is that each record contain serveral field."   Related to your string, what is a record and what is a field?

Comment: record delimiter is '#', field delimiter is ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly there, try something like this:

```
public function splitDouble(source:String,rSeparator:String,fSeparator:String):ArrayCollection{
            var records:Array = source.split(rSeparator);
            var result:Array = [];
            for (var i : int = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                result[i] = records[i].split(fSeparator);
            }
            return new ArrayCollection(result);
        }
```

For brevity you could use the [every()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#every%28%29) function, but I think it's simpler/cleaner without an anonymous function or something like that.